# Unable to wait for a response that just hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am runing a node script that processes an array of string with a package called `string-strip-html`. Some urls have some content that the package is unable to process it does not error out it just gets stucked and the CPU goes to 100%.

```
// Long sting of html that the package struggles to process
const string = `a long string of html`

try {
 // The package gets stuck here
 const clean = stripHtml(string).result
} catch(err) {
 // This never runs
 console.log(err)
}
```

When this happens I want to be able to skip it after a few seconds, should I use a setTimeout of a setInterval?

Comment: Since it's a synchronous implementation, you can't stop it, it'll just be blocking the Node.js event loop. I would suggest you start looking for a replacement package.

Comment: The whole thing runs on a async function, would that make a difference?

Comment: Does the function `stripHtml` return a promise? Perhaps using `await` before it will help.

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: In the end I change the package to `striptags`